# Matlab svds function incompatible with symbolic data

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, matlab, svd, computer-algebra-systems

I am currently working with very small numbers and hence in order to increase Matlab's precision I have made use of Matlab's `vpa` function which turns a $n\times n$ double into a $n\times n$ symbolic data structure. I wish to compute the top 20 singular values for such a matrix however the only Matlab function which can compute singular values for the symbolic structure is `svd`. This however computes all singular values, and when we consider large matrices (e.g. $2^{12}\times 2^{12}$) this becomes computationally expensive.

I am aware that the functions `svds` exists which computes a subset of the singular values however this is incompatible with the symbolic data type. Is anyone aware of a Matlab function which computes a subset of all the singular values that can interpret the symbolic data structure that is also not computationally expensive?

Comment: Why not rescaling your matrix?

Comment: Hi @KBS! Would you please be able to elaborate on this further?

Comment: You can always rescale your matrix by a constant factor to avoid working with too small numbers. If the entries of a matrix $A$ are of the order of, say, $10^{-n}$, then you can consider the matrix $B$ such that $A=10^{-n}B$, and perform the operations on the matrix $B$. This is a standard procedure. You may also need to consider sparse matrices to save memory and reduce computation time.